# How can I change the width of a RelativeLayout that has a GridLayout as child?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

The Idea is with the help of a Touch listener on the RelativeLayout to change the size (width and height) of itself. The child inside of the RelativeLayout is a GridLayout that itself consists of Multiple FrameLayouts (Which I guess is not relevant). The GridLayout has its width and height set to match_parent(as in the RelativeLayout). The theory is that the GridLayout should change according to its parent on runtime.

But whenever I try to change the Parameters of the RelativeLayout I get this error message:

*android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams*

Here is the relevant part of the XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/maingrid">


        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="4"
            android:id="@+id/grid">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1">
```

Here is the code

```
          private RelativeLayout Wall = findViewById(R.id.maingrid);

          Wall.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth,newHeight));
```

I have tried to change RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to other classes trying to work around the Exception error. But I just get other similar Exception Errors thrown my way. Think I might be missing something.

Is it even possible to use the above XML Layout structure and produce the required behaviour at runtime

Edited

---

maybe I should have mentioned that the XML File with the GridLayout is included into the main layout below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.lucy.pixelli.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/grid" />
```

This is the Full Error Message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lucy.pixelli, PID: 11119
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.getViewWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:877)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:643)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:631)
at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:971)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6127)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:694)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19978)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2405)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1457)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1720)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1333)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6675)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:887)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:699)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:634)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code, any fields of type FrameLayout you have, also show which line does the stack trace say the exception is thrown at? The stack trace itself would be nice as well

Comment: Oh whow, actually found out that I did have a FrameLayout set somewhere else totally unrelated to the scenario I described above, causing the Error (sorry for that). Got rid of that and edited the Question, because im still getting an Exception Error see above. it has something to do with the parent of my RelativeLayout. Expanded the XML file aswell so that you can see the ConstrainedLayout.

Comment: Im googling around and somehow im apparently getting this error because  im making a call to the parent of the RelativeLayout. But all I want is to change the size of RealtiveLayout that holds the GridLayout. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set `LayoutParams` to you `RelativeLayout`.

`LayoutParams` of a view should be of the type of the parent of that view.

Since your `RelativeLayout` is contained within a `ConstraintLayout`, then your `LayoutParams` should be of `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParam`.

For `LayoutParams` with only `width/height`, you can just use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: Tried  using ViewGroup.LayoutParams got an Exception error that it cannot be set to constraint.

Comment: Buuut, Setting it to ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams works perfectly. Thank you very much, took me  hours to get this to work.